# Regular Expression issue in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, regex

I am trying to work with following pattern.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#{{[[[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}]]}}" options:0 error:&error];
NSString *originalMesssage = @"test  #{{[[8-16-5]]}}";
NSArray *arrResults = [regex matchesInString:originalMesssage options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalMesssage length])];
```

I want "8-16-5" as return value after filtering with above Regex. appearently the problem is with "{}" & "[]" characters.
I have tested same pattern with http://regexpal.com/ and it is working fine there.
1) is there any wildcard characters which i should use in my above code?

References: [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Following is the code which finally worked for me.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#\\{\\{\\[\\[[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}\\]\\]\\}\\}" options:0 error:&error];
NSString *originalMesssage = @"test  #{{[[8-16-5]]}}";
NSArray *arrResults = [regex matchesInString:originalMesssage options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalMesssage length])];


NSTextCheckingResult *match = [arrResults objectAtIndex:0];
NSRange matchRange = [match range];
NSString *resultString = [originalMesssage substringWithRange:matchRange];
```

Comment: Please list your current results instead of just saying "the problem".

Comment: i am getting following error after using this

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" UserInfo=0xa3529a0 {NSInvalidValue=#{{[[[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}]]}}}

Comment: @MikeM I think he might just have poor English... He probably meant he wants "8-16-5" returned from the string (so the RegEx strips out everything else.)

Comment: @MikeM your comment made me laugh at first until I realized what the user was actually asking haha.

Comment: @MikeM sorry for lack of description there. i have edited post. AlbertRenshaw have described problem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[`, `]`, `{`, and `}` characters have special meanings in regular expressions. You need to escape them:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\#\\{\\{\\[\\[[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}-[0-9]{1,10}\\]\\]\\}\\}" options:0 error:&error];
NSString *originalMesssage = @"test  #{{[[8-16-5]]}}";
NSArray *arrResults = [regex matchesInString:originalMesssage options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalMesssage length])];
```

Comment: You should actually use double backslashes "\\" so that the resulting string has a single backslash before each escaped character. Lone backslashes in string literals in C/Obj-C will escape the character that follows them, but we want those backslashes to survive in the pattern string so the regex engine knows what should be escaped.

Comment: @warrenm yes, adding "\\" instead of "\" working for me.
Thanks.